# vSphere web client error [400] An error occurred while sending an authentication request

Tags: webclient, vmware, vsphere, vcenter

I have got an issue after I have restarted my vCenter VM in my ESXi Host. The error says:
[400] An error occurred while sending an authentication request to the vCenter Single Sign-On server - An error occurred when processing the metadata during vCenter Single Sign-On setup - Failed to connect to VMware Lookup Service - https://10.20.30.50:443/lookupservice/sdk

I tried to find something googling but unfortunately, I couldn't find anything...
Could someone please help me? I can't believe, that just a restart can provide this kind of issues... :(

Answer (score 1):

https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/71387

This is an expected behavior.
VMware vSphere 7.0 enforce FQDN or IP address reverse resolvable to FQDN to allow authentication for Single-Sign on.

Comment: Please provide answer in the answer, don't link to external resources

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with the vCenter's service discovery and the vSphere Client basically cannot find its authentication service.

Try to restart VMware Lookup Service from the vCenter Server Management UI (the one on port 5480), subsection *Services*. If the problem persists, check the lookup service logs. If running the vCenter appliance and not Windows, they should be somewhere under */var/log/vmware*...

Have you changed fundamental configuration of vCenter before restart e.g. changing the vCenter host name or root certificates?

Did you contact VMware support?